# Mixing Bind mode and manual added items in Telerik's TreeView for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, treeview, telerik

I'm using Telerik's Treeview for ASP.NET MVC2/3.
I've set it up to bind to my entity objects tree (I have about 4 levels)

I want to add anothe level (5th) that is manual added:

```
+ Country
--+ City
-----+ Street
---------View Places
---------Find Distance
```

County, City, Street comes from DB, I want to add to each node at the end 2 fixed sub-items -- is it possible? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done unless you manipulate somehow the tree at runtime and inject nodes after it is bound to your objects...

Comment: I am afraid you might be right. I might add them manually to the Object Tree in the controller. If nothing pop out I'll accept this answer :-)